# arp is displaying weird IP addresses in the 169 range

Tags: networking, dhcp, routing

I just ran arp: I'm a naturally curious person and from time to time, I like to run random commands out of complete boredom

It returned:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
169.254.210.73                   (incomplete)                              wlp2s0
192.168.2.3                      (incomplete)                              wlp2s0
router.Belkin            ether   94:10:3e:f8:12:b3   C                     wlp2s0
192.168.2.119                    (incomplete)                              wlp2s0
169.254.153.105                  (incomplete)                              wlp2s0
169.254.158.127                  (incomplete)                              wlp2s0
169.254.79.15                    (incomplete)                              wlp2s0
```

I've tracerouted all of the 169 addresses and they all bounce back to my machine.

I've just flushed the arp table and rebooted the router. All the IP addresses persist and they're exactly the same as before. They traceroute back to my computer as well.

ifconfig shows these interfaces:

```
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
bond0     1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMm
enp1s0    1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
lo       65536  1383953      0      0 0       1383953      0      0      0 LRU
vboxnet0  1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BM
wlp2s0    1500  3890437      0      1 0       2289353      0      0      0 BMRU
```

When running: sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all

```
192.168.2.1 dev wlp2s0 lladdr 94:10:3e:f8:12:b3 ref 1 used 62/26/16 probes 4 REACHABLE

*** Round 1, deleting 1 entries ***
*** Flush is complete after 1 round ***
```

Comment: They are supposed to, the 169 address is a self assigned IP

Comment: Why are there so many of them and what caused me to need a self-assigned IP?

Comment: That's a self assigned link local IPv4 address, it happens when a device is unable to acquire a dhcp address. Im assuming it's either other devices or you have multiple interfaces.

Comment: ifconfig isn't showing more than the usual interfaces (wlp2s0, enp1s0). Even the inactive interfaces are all accounted for. Since the addresses point to my machine, I'd assume it wasn't other devices. I've also rebooted the router and it persists with the same IP addresses.

Comment: Someone Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that's just an arp cache, since there is no actual hardware address it's not assigned to any interface, and could be a previous entry

Comment: @nullmeta, is there any way to clear it? I've flushed my IP table and rebooted my router.

Comment: What exact arp command did you run initially, and what command did you use to flush the arp cache?

Comment: I ran "arp" and then to flush the ip table, I ran "sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all"

Comment: How about `sudo arp -d <ip address> `

Comment: I just ran arp (to get the addresses for removal) again and they've all disappeared.

Comment: I'm assuming the flush worked then, good :)

Comment: I see those in arpwatch from my Windoze virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

Addresses in the `169.254.x.x` range are self assigned link local IP addresses. It usually happens when a device is unable to acquire an IP from a DHCP server. Those entries aren't necessarily hurting anything however you can flush the `arp` cache:

```
sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all
```

Should flush the `arp` cache.

Otherwise you can use `arp` from `net-tools` to delete a specific IP from `arp` cache:

```
sudo arp -d <ip address>
```

(`-d` is for delete).